# Convert 1x1 sparse matrix to scalar

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

The dot product of a row and column in a matrix is a 1x1 `csr_matrix`. How can I efficiently convert that to a scalar? Right now I use `sum`. `M` below is a square matrix:

```
dot_product_result = csr_matrix.sum(M.getrow(3).dot(M.getcol(5)))
```

[Here's the `lil_matrix` documentation.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html)

**UPDATE** When I try the solution below, I get this error:

```
    raise NotImplementedError('adding a nonzero scalar to a '
NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported
```

This is the actual code I'm using:

```
 e = rating - Q.getrow(mid).dot(P.getcol(uid))[0]
 iteration_error += e
```

I initialize `iteration_error` to 0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M[3,:].dot(M[:,5])[0,0]`

Also, calling `csr_matrix.sum` like that is not very good style: it's an instance method, so should be called as `M[3,:].dot(M[:,5]).sum()`

Comment: I converted `Q.getrow(mid)` to `Q[mid, :]` as you suggested. now I get this warning: `SparseEfficiencyWarning: Indexing into a lil_matrix with multiple indices is slow. Pre-converting to CSC or CSR beforehand is more efficient.`. Should I use `getrow` instead?

Comment: You should measure which one is faster.

Comment: Yowza, getrow is about 20x faster than indexing! Here's the test I wrote: http://lpaste.net/100041

Comment: Thank you! Can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817378/efficiently-assign-a-row-to-a-lil-matrix