# Efficiently assign a row to a lil_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I efficiently assign a row to a `lil_matrix`? I'm currently using:

```
Q[mid, :] = new_Q
```

where `new_Q` is the result of `lil_matrix.getrow(x)`

I ran a test on using `Q.getrow(i)` vs. `Q[i, :]`, and found the former to be 20x faster.

[Here's the `lil_matrix` documentation.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html)

Comment: In general, I'd just avoid using the LIL format whenever possible. Of course you'd need to benchmark for your use case, but I expect there is a faster format you can use.

Comment: Which format should I use? I'm only modifying one column of matrix A at a time, and modifying one column of matrix B at a time. I considered `csr_matrix` and `csc_matrix`, but I found this note: "Note that assigning to a CSR/CSC matrix is in general a bad idea.  Any change to the sparsity structure of these formats requires O(nnz) operations, which basically means reconstructing the matrix from scratch."

Comment: Are you modifying columns or rows?  `lil` is good for rows, since each row is represented by simple elements in 2 lists.  Working with specific columns requires accessing elements within many nested lists.

Comment: I meant to say, "I'm modifying one ROW of matrix A at a time, and modifying one COLUMN of B at a time." It sounds like I should create A as a `lil_matrix`. What type of matrix should B be?

Answer (score 1):

These time tests on small `lil` (dense, but I don't think that matters), suggest that `x[i,:]` is not a problem setting.  Yes, for some reason, it is slow when used to fetch a row.

```
In [108]: x=sparse.lil_matrix(np.arange(120).reshape(24,5))

In [109]: timeit x[10,:]=10
1000 loops, best of 3: 235 us per loop

In [110]: timeit y=x.getrowview(10);y[:]=10
1000 loops, best of 3: 291 us per loop

In [111]: timeit x[10,:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 658 us per loop

In [112]: timeit x.getrowview(10)
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.4 us per loop
```

The source for `getrowview` is instructive, showing how the underlying data structures for this matrix are handled.

```
def getrowview(self, i):
    """Returns a view of the 'i'th row (without copying).
    """
    new = lil_matrix((1, self.shape[1]), dtype=self.dtype)
    new.rows[0] = self.rows[i]
    new.data[0] = self.data[i]
    return new
```

I think `x[10,:]` uses `x.__getitem__` or `x.__setitem__`.  Both of those functions are more complicated than this `getrowview`.  I'm guessing `x.__getitem__` is slow because it is also indexing on columns (see. `x._get1`).  `x[10,:]` takes just as much time as `x[10,0:5]`.

Indicative of what might be accomplished if you only need to set one row, and access `rows` and `data` directly:

```
In [133]: timeit x.rows[10]=range(5);x.data[10]=[10]*5
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 us per loop
```

This is far from general, but it gives an idea of what you can do in special cases.

---

Some more timings:

```
In [156]: timeit x[10,:]=x.getrow(12)[:,:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 940 us per loop

In [157]: timeit x[10,:]=x.getrow(12)
1000 loops, best of 3: 259 us per loop
```

That extra `[:,:]` is slow.  `getrow` already returns a copy, so it probably is not needed.

```
In [160]: timeit b=x.getrowview(10);b=x.getrow(12)
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 us per loop

In [169]: timeit x.rows[10],x.data[10] = x.rows[12][:],x.data[12][:]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 us per loop
```

Direct modification of `rows` and `data` needs to be tested carefully.